# jQuery update script tag - rewrite all content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem with jquery. 
I want change link to src when is only "document.write".

My code:
myscript.js

```
document.write("TEST ABCD");
```

test.html

```
<html>
<body>
  <button id="example">click me</button>
<div>my site example text</div>
  <div id="my_div_important">
    Old test
  </div>  
  <script>
  $(function(){
    $('#example').on('click',function(){
      $('<script>').attr('src', 'http://example.com/script.js').appendTo('#my_div_important');
    });
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If click "#example" than in page write: TEST ABCD but all the rest is HIDDEN... URL is to same (no redirect).

When is problem?

--- UPDATE

I want to do a widget where users will use on their sites.

The panel of users want to do a preview of different sizes and therefore need to update the script SRC tag script (example.com/widget/normal/250|300 itp.)

Comment: You want to load a script dynamically or what??? And please, if posting complete HTML markup, then at least include all relevant one. What about jQuery?!

Comment: I want to do a widget where people pasting on your website... You have an idea?

Comment: Ok, i think i understand your expected behaviour

Comment: Cannot you just use in `script.js`: `$('#my_div_important').html("TEST ABCD");` ?

Comment: because this code will be on the siteof other people (widget).

Comment: But what is your expected result? Adding content of loaded script inside its parent element? I mean where your user decides to put the script tag? If ya, then target it by attribute src to get its relevant parent. Following your edit, i'm lost getting what you are expecting, sorry... `The panel of users want to do a preview of different sizes and therefore need to update the script SRC tag script` **???**

Comment: Members of the panel viewer preview widget, but I want to give a preview when you change the size of the input panel.

Answer (score 0):

document.write deletes all the content if your page is already fully loaded (as you do a write on the document object).

Also you should use [jQuery.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) for dynamic loading of scripts.